# How to fix hiding datagridview object

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm setting datagridview as object and show in windows form in Textbox change event. When open form and start texting into textbox then datagridview is show but when text is empty or null datagridview continue been visible. How can I accomplish datagridview invisible in windows form?

This is for C#. I have tried to dispose datagridview in if clause but it didn't work.

Here is my code:

```
public class CreateDataGridView
    {
        public DataGridView clientsDgv = new DataGridView();

        public CreateDataGridView()
        {
            clientsDgv.ReadOnly = true;
            clientsDgv.Name = "clientsDgv";
            clientsDgv.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
            clientsDgv.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
            clientsDgv.AllowUserToResizeRows = false;  
        }

        public DataGridView Createdgv()
        {
            return clientsDgv;
        }
```

Here is my code in windows form.

```
//Get datagridview in windows form textbox change event



private void TxtID_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            switch (this.cmbSelectAction.SelectedIndex)
            {
                case 1:

                    CreateDataGridView clientsdgv = new CreateDataGridView();
                    //clientsdgv.clientsDgv
                    Controls.Add(clientsdgv.clientsDgv);
                    clientsdgv.clientsDgv.BringToFront();


                    DesignDataGridView designdgv = new DesignDataGridView();

                    designdgv.ClientsDataGridFormatting(clientsdgv.clientsDgv);
                    designdgv.ClientsDataGridPosition(clientsdgv.clientsDgv, txtID);
                    //SetDoubleBuffered.SetDoubleBuffering(clientsdgv.clientsDgv, true);



                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtID.Text) || txtID.Text == "0")
                    {
                        clientsdgv.clientsDgv.DataSource = null;
                        clientsdgv.clientsDgv.Update();
                        clientsdgv.clientsDgv.Dispose();
                        clientsdgv.clientsDgv.Visible = false;
                        return;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        GetSqlData getSqlData = new GetSqlData();

                        try
                        {
                            clientsdgv.clientsDgv.SuspendLayout();
                            columnName = "PersonalIDBulstat";
                            ID = txtID.Text;
                            clientsdgv.clientsDgv.Visible = true;
                            clientsdgv.clientsDgv.DataSource = getSqlData.SearchClientsInSql(columnName, ID);
                            clientsdgv.clientsDgv.Update();
                            clientsdgv.clientsDgv.ResumeLayout();
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            title = "Clients";
                            SetMessageBoxTypes.MessageBoxContactAdminOk(title);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `[yourDataGridView].Visible = false;` will make it invisible. What exactly doesn't work for you?

Comment: This is not hide datagridview (clientsdgv.clientsDgv.Visible = false; )  in first if clause " if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtID.Text) || txtID.Text == "0")"

Comment: _Doesn't work_ is not  a helpful problem description! - Did you try the [debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx), your very best friend in the world of coding. - Also: Do not Dispose of the DGV if you want to hide it!

Comment: Hi Taw! Yes I have tried debugger and if textbox is empty or null then goes in first if clause and have to dispose datagridview and hide it, but it didn't happened. I have tried to remove dispose but it didn't work.

Comment: Why are you disposing it if your intention is to hide it? Just set the Visible property to false, no need to dispose it.

Comment: If I use datagridview create from Toolbox in the same windows form it worked and hide datagridview when textbox is empty or null. There is something wrong maybe when I create datagridview as object.

Comment: You seem to be creating a new instance of CreateDataGridView on every TextChanged event (which then may or may not be visible). I very much doubt that this is what you intended.

Instead, you may want to create an instance on the first call, and hold on to that reference (e.g. in a member variable of your form). On subsequent TextChanged events, you then just set the visibility of that one instance.

Comment: Thank you so much pniederh! Now it works with pleasure! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

It is my working code when form is load where dgvClients is declare as DataGridView:

```
     private void Clients_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
              CreateDataGridView clientsdgv = new CreateDataGridView();
              dgvClients = clientsdgv.dgvClients;
             }



private void TxtID_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            switch (this.cmbSelectAction.SelectedIndex)
            {
                case 1:

                    Controls.Add(dgvClients);
                    dgvClients.BringToFront();


                    DesignDataGridView designdgv = new DesignDataGridView();
                    designdgv.ClientsDataGridPosition(dgvClients, this.txtID);


                    GetSqlData getSqlData = new GetSqlData();

                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtID.Text) || txtID.Text == "0")
                    {

                        dgvClients.DataSource = null;
                        dgvClients.Update();
                        dgvClients.Visible = false;
                        return;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            dgvClients.SuspendLayout();
                            columnName = "PersonalIDBulstat";
                            ID = txtID.Text;
                            dgvClients.Visible = true;
                            dgvClients.DataSource = getSqlData.SearchClientsInSql(columnName, ID);
                            dgvClients.Update();
                            dgvClients.ResumeLayout();
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            title = "Clients";
                            SetMessageBoxTypes.MessageBoxContactAdminOk(title);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I believe that the line `Controls.Add(dgvClients);` should also be moved from the method `TxtID_TextChanged` to `Clients_Load`, so that it is executed only once, not on every text change.